How to remove rows based on values in two columns
I have a data frame with 35 columns and about 250,000 rows. Depending on the values in the year column and the network_id column I want to remove some rows. The specification of which to remove is given in this list:
remove.nets <- list(r19=c(14, 31),
                    r21=c(31),
                    r23=c(32),
                    r24=c(1, 4, 8, 24, 30, 59))

So if the year is 2019 and the network ID is either 14 or 31, remove the row, and similarly for other rows. I tried something like this:
test.data2 <- test.data %>%
     {if (year==2019) filter(., !network_id %in% remove.nets$r19)}

This seemed to me to be an obvious way to do this but it didn't work. (It threw errors that I don't understand).
Error in year == 2019 : 
  comparison (==) is possible only for atomic and list types

I had to make a data frame out of the remove.nets list and do an anti_join like this:
remove.nets <- data.frame(year=c(2019, 2019, 2021, 2023, rep(2024, 6)),
                          network_id=c(14, 31, 31, 32, 1, 4, 8, 24, 30, 59))
anti_join(., remove.nets, by=c("year", "network_id"))


This works but it's aesthetically un-pleasing. Can anyone help me make it easier and prettier?

Please provide a small sample of test.data using dput(). See [MRE] for guidance.

What do you mean by aesthetically unpleasing? It's an efficient, clear, concise approach and will be hard to beat by any objective measure I can think of.

There's nothing aesthetically unpleasing about anti_join. To get the data frame from the list, just do:
remove.nets.df <- data.frame(year=rep(sub('r', 20, names(remove.nets)), 
                                      sapply(remove.nets, length)),
                             network_id=unlist(remove.nets))

And then:
library(dplyr)

anti_join(test.data, remove.nets.df, by=c("year", "network_id"))


Ah, I see. That tricky bit of code to convert the list into a data frame is just what I need. Thank you very much. What I thought was aesthetically unpleasing was having to convert the list into a data frame by hand.
